# Want to save Audio word in text file

Tags: audio, audio-converter

I searched and found that it is possible to save audio word in a text file from a recorded audio file. Also found few softwares are available for this.
But don't get any algorithm or solution which is applicable for saving recognized audio word from live audio into a text file. 
is there any expert or researcher who can help me to solve this problem? 
Advance thanks to all expert.

Answer (score 0):

What's your environment? Nowadays it could be possible online too!
Take a look here [at Google Dev](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2013/01/Voice-Driven-Web-Apps-Introduction-to-the-Web-Speech-API)

Comment: Gianlu environment isn't matter. I just want to save word into text file. Thanks